# Font Awesome Ruby Gem fonts not loading

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I am using the font-awesome gem.  I have it in my gem file as follows:

```
gem "font-awesome-sass"
```

The css appears to be loading properly, as the classes are in my application.css.scss file.  However, the fonts are not loading.  I just get the "square" indicating that the font isn't loading.

Anybody have any ideas as to what might be going on?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [this issue says that the asset path is incorrect in font-awesome-sass Gem](https://github.com/volkanunsal/font-awesome-sass/commit/301d1d451d4cbbd981bf635c3ed9778b8a94ab95).

Try using this alternative [font awesome rails](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails) .

Comment: Unfortunately, still getting the same issue.  Thanks.